# How to process requests in Python through an Express server

Tags: node.js, express

My approach has been to write a `Flask` server in Python and forward the request to that.

Demo.py

```
from flask import Flask

app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Alternately, I also tried directly invoking a `python` script and then collecting the result from `stdout`.

Trial.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const pyProg = spawn('python', ['C:/Users/Selectigence/PycharmProjects/jobapplicationbot/Sample3.py']);

    pyProg.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

        console.log(data.toString());
        res.write(data);
        res.end('end');
    });
})

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Application listening on port 4000!'))
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want your express server to receive the HTTP request and then use some code in python to process it?

Comment: Yes,I want to execute all python functions/methods through web. but i want to execute through node js, because i want to run multiple python script though node js.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. I was running a Node JS server but the client request had to be processed in Python. So I went for an architecture which went like this:

[image: Server Architecture]

The *Web process* was the Node JS server and the *Background service* was written in Python.

To implement this architecture, I had to answer the following questions:

1. How to implement the *Background service*.
2. How to get the *Background service* to communicate with the *Web process*.

I used [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) to implement my *Background service*. For example:

`tasks.py`

```
import os
from celery import Celery

REDIS_URL='redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
app = Celery('tasks', backend=REDIS_URL, broker='REDIS_URL')

@app.task
def doSomething(arguments):
    # Do whatever you want with the arguments 
    # and return the result ...
    return result
```

My *Web process* was defined as follows:

`app.js`

```
const celery = require("node-celery");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const REDIS_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379";

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  const client = celery.createClient({
    CELERY_BROKER_URL: REDIS_URL,
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: REDIS_URL
  });

  client.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

  client.on("connect", function() {
    const { arguments } = req.body;
    // Here send task to Python process and 
    // process the result.
    client.call("tasks.doSomething", [arguments], result => {
      // The result object contains the result 
      // of the doSomething function in the "result"
      // field along with other information regarding 
      // whether the call was successful.
      res.send({ result: result.result });
      client.end();
    });
  });
});

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Application listening on port 4000!'))
```

Now I needed a communication channel between these two processes. I used [redis](https://redis.io/) as the message broker.

In the command line, I ran:

```
$ redis-server &
$ npm start &
$ celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO &
```

Now, whenever I send a GET request at the server through the browser, the server forwards the arguments in the request to the Python service. This service processes the arguments, and returns the result to the server. The server finally fulfills the request with the response which is sent back to the browser.